# Is MVVM a common design pattern between different platforms?

Tags: mvvm

Is it possible to adopt [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mvvm/info) design pattern in one platform such as windows phone and implement the code the way that is portable to other platforms like android and iOS regarding data binding?

Or I’d better ask if MVVM design pattern is common between different platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, which is applicable to all platforms. MVVM is a variation based on the various DataBinding features in WPF. At least that's the context where the term MVVM is most commonly used.

While the pattern itself is portable, you won't be able to use your Windows Phone code for platforms like Android or iOS.

Answer (score 1):

While the pattern might be applicable in different plattforms the implementation won't be (for example iOS's Objective-C / device-specific APIs vs. Windows Phones *C#* / Silverlight).

Only solution might be going HTML5/CSS/JavaScript - I think you might be able to use MVVM there but it's more a technology than an pattern thing.

Comment: Actually I thought design patterns are technology agnostic, aren’t they?

Comment: sure but MVVM is using lots of tools (for example binding in WPF/Silverlight) to really make it shine. How usefull is it to **reuse** an idiom accross plattforms if you have to adapt and rewrite all the code?

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of MVVM pattern using JavaScript and HTML (thus making it very portable):

http://knockoutjs.com

Since there are at least two very different platforms and libraries that allow you to easily use this pattern, the answer is YES.